# Trigger activates script, but nothing happens | Send email

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script whose purpose is to send an email when the "Name" and "Link" columns are filled, using the time trigger. However, there are times when it works and others when it doesn't. Most of the time, when the time trigger is activated, it executes as "completed," but nothing happens. None of the two functions in the code is performed.

Could someone help me correct this script or create another one with the same objective?

```js
function getFirstWord() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Check if the active sheet is "AUTOMATION"
  if (sheet.getName() !== "AUTOMATION") {
    return;
  }

  const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  const lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    const fullName = dataRange.getValues()[i - 1][1];
    const firstWord = fullName.split(" ")[0];

    sheet.getRange(i, 12).setValue(firstWord);
  }
}

function sendEmails() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Check if the active sheet is "AUTOMATION"
  if (sheet.getName() !== "AUTOMATION") {
    return;
  }

  const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  const lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    const email = dataRange.getValues()[i - 1][3];
    const name = dataRange.getValues()[i - 1][11];
    const link = dataRange.getValues()[i - 1][12];
    const status = sheet.getRange(i, 14).getValue();

    const message = `Hello ${name}!\n\nHere is the Smartplan Spreadsheet.\n*Pay attention to the instructions, they are few but important!*\n\n1) Watch the step-by-step video\nhttps://youtu.be/jGMrjpvwayY\n\n2) If you are using a mobile device, remember to download/update the GOOGLE SHEETS app before accessing the spreadsheet link\n\n3) Save the link below to your favorites; this is the link you will ALWAYS use to access your spreadsheet.\n\n4) Access the spreadsheet link:\n${link}`;

    if (name && name.length > 0 && status !== "Sent") {
      const cc = "daphnemelooo@gmail.com"; 
      if (GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Email Subject", message, { cc: cc })) {
        sheet.getRange(i, 14).setValue("Sent");
      } else {
        sheet.getRange(i, 14).setValue("Error");
      }
    }
  }
}

getFirstWord();
sendEmails();
```

Sheets Teste: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DqthJ8wX8C0WTuWp74rT8TKnSudVl4cP8IXBHCU5NTc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In your sendEmails function, change the first line to get the "AUTOMATION" sheet directly instead of getting the the active sheet and then checking if it is "AUTOMATION". Replace the line to this :-  
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AUTOMATION");
I guess the reason why it didn't work sometimes was because your active sheet might have been different than AUTOMATION. This change should solve the issue. Please try and let me know if any issues.

Comment: @ab.it.gcp, Yes, it worked, thank you!I had to make a change to the code (swapping gmailApp for MailApp) and it's causing a similar problem. I have two different spreadsheets, both with the same "Automation" tab. The script works in spreadsheet 1 but doesn't work in spreadsheet 2. Anyway, I'm going to create another question to post the code and try to solve this problem.